# ARIMA process with automated coding in r

Tags: r, time-series

I have a series `lnPrice` with 3069 observations.

```
library(forecast)
####fitting the model#####AR_1_3039
AR_1_3039 <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[1:3039]), order=c(1,1,0))
summary(AR_1_3039)

####fitting the model#####AR_1_3040
AR_1_3040 <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[2:3040]), order=c(1,1,0))
summary(AR_1_3040)

####fitting the model#####AR_1_3041
AR_1_3041 <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[3:3041]), order=c(1,1,0))
summary(AR_1_3041)

####fitting the model#####AR_1_3042
AR_1_3042 <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[4:3042]), order=c(1,1,0))
summary(AR_1_3042)

####fitting the model#####AR_1_3043
AR_1_3043 <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[5:3043]), order=c(1,1,0))
summary(AR_1_3043)
```

I am aiming to generate 30 ARIMA(1,1,0) models with sliding sample as you can understand above mentioned codes. For example AR(1)_3039 model has `usdtry$lnPrice[1:3039]`, while AR(1)_3040 has `usdtry$lnPrice[2:3040]` and finally  AR(1)_3068 will be having `usdtry$lnPrice[30:3068]`.

I would like to write a dynamic coding for this process in r. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I use `forecast` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by "dynamic", but I'll understand it as something along the lines of "automated". So here's a simple `for` loop which will index the rows you want, by 1 unit each loop.

```
storage <- list()
summary_storage <- list()

    for(i in 1:30){
  storage[[paste0("AR_1_", i)]] <- Arima((usdtry$lnPrice[i:3039+i]),order=c(1,1,0))
  summary_storage[[paste0("Summary AR_1_", i)]] <- summary(storage[[paste0("AR_1_",i)]])
}
```

Essentially what I'm doing is running an ARIMA on your data, putting the model output into the list "storage", and then doing the same for the summary stats, i think the summary stats will be quite ugly, but i don't know if that is avoidable.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is giving:`Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Comment: `Error: unexpected ']' in:
"i:3039+i]),order=c(1,1,0))
{if (.Revo.tb("C:/Users")) browser()};  summary_storage[[paste0("Summary AR_1_", i)]] "`

Comment: Strange, could you copy the code and try again? If that doesn't work, It might be easier if you post some of your data so i can check my code.

Comment: It is ok now! Appreciated!